# How return function in loop (for .. of ..) javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, dom

```
    const btnSearch = [...document.querySelectorAll('a.validate')];
    const fieldNik = document.getElementsByClassName('form-nik');
    window.validate = function () {
        for(const i of btnSearch.keys()){
            btnSearch[i].onclick = function(){
                var validate = true;
                let identity = $(fieldNik[i]).val().replaceAll(' ', '').replaceAll('_', '');    
                if (!identity) {
                    bootbox.alert('NIK Tidak Boleh Kosong !');
                    validate = false;
                } else if (identity[0] == '0') {
                    bootbox.alert('NIK tidak valid. Digit pertama tidak boleh 0');
                    validate = false;
                } else if (identity[1] == '0') {
                    bootbox.alert('NIK tidak valid. Digit kedua tidak boleh 0');
                    validate = false;
                } else if (identity.substr(12) == '0000') {
                    bootbox.alert('NIK tidak valid. 4 Digit terakhir tidak boleh nol');
                    validate = false;
                } else if (identity.length < 16) {
                    bootbox.alert('NIK harus 16 digit !');
                    validate = false;
                }
                return validate;
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to do validation in button with dataset:

```
data-validatefunc="validate"
```

My question: how `return validate;` in this func `window.validate` ? I tried doing in `window.validate`, but it still failed. whether this loop function cannot return value like `forEach()`?

Answer (score 0):

You did not define a return for `validate()`.. just returns for the button-click-events. You should make a standalone `validate()` function with a return and then assign that function to the buttons.

Here is a brief example:

```
//REM: Validation function as whole standalone function
function validate(){
    var fieldNik = document.getElementsByClassName('form-nik');
    var validate = true;

    //REM: Whatever comes inbetween
    //REM: Actual validation

    return validate
};

//REM: Assigning the validation function to the button click-event
const btnSearch = [...document.querySelectorAll('a.validate')];
for(const i of btnSearch.keys()){
    btnSearch[i].onclick = validate
};
```

Whether you call it `validate` or `window.validate` does not matter in your context, since `this` is `window`.